# TYPO3 v9 pages accessible through URL like /page/<pageId>/

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

How can I do with the new Routing API to make pages accessible through something like `https://example.com/page/{idOfThePage}`? Normal slug behavior with page title still needs to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to just adapt the page slugs in the page properties. For many pages you can do that in the DB (field `pages.slug`).

If you want new pages and the slug autogeneration in the backend to follow that, too you can [overwrite](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html) `EXT:core`s [pages TCA](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/TCA/pages.php#L173) in your `TCA/Overrides/pages.php` ([docs TCA type `slug`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Slug.html)).

I suggest (not tested):

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['slug']['config']['generatorOptions']['fields'] = ['uid'];
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['slug']['config']['generatorOptions']['prefixParentPageSlug'] = false;
```

I have no idea how to get the base `/page` in there. You could set your site's base path to `/page` in site config maybe? Or you might need a [generatorOptions[postModifier]](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Slug.html#generatoroptions).

Notice:

A routeEnhancer might come to mind first for rewriting URLs. And yes, for other simple parameters a [SimpleEnhancer](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html#simple-enhancer) is able to do that - yet for the base path/pageUid it is not.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the normal behavior of pages slug still needs to work so pages need to be accessible through /{pageTitleTransformedBySlug} also.

Comment: that's a bit unfair now. I put quite some effort into my answer ;) I hope you find a solution then